# jQuery/JavaScript: Triggering a click function on same-page anchors

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

A website I'm developing has a list of links in the footer on every page. These links are appended with anchors like so:

```
<ul>
    <li class="lines exp"><a href="services.html#sa">Service A</a></li>
    <li class="lines exp"><a href="services.html#sb">Service B</a></li>
    <li class="lines exp"><a href="services.html#sc">Service C</a></li>
</ul>
```

On the "services.html" target page for these links, there is a series of toggle-style divs each corresponding to the above anchored links, like so:

```
<div id="sa" class="toggle-trigger">
    <h3 class="services-title">
        <a class="toggle-text">Service A</a>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="toggle-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolorem.</p>
</div>
<div id="sb" class="toggle-trigger">
    <h3 class="services-title">
        <a class="toggle-text">Service B</a>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="toggle-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolorem.</p>
</div>
<div id="sc" class="toggle-trigger">
    <h3 class="services-title">
        <a class="toggle-text">Service C</a>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="toggle-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolorem.</p>
</div>
```

The ultimate goal is to have the footer links activate their target "toggle-trigger" div with a simulated click event, which will toggle open the associated "toggle-container" div after loading the "services.html" page.

To this end, I've added the following JavaScript / jQuery to "services.html" at the end of the body, since it should only fire once the page is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var target = document.URL;
        var regex = /services\.html#[a-z]{2}$/;
        var result = regex.exec(target);
        console.log("Target / Regex / Result: " + target + " / " + regex + " / " + result);
        if (result) {
            var divID = /#[a-z]{2}/.exec(result);
            console.log("divID: " + divID[0]);
            $(divID[0]).delay(1000).trigger('click');
        }
    });
    $(".exp").click(function() {
        var target = window.location.hash;
        console.log("Target: " + target);
        $(target).delay(1000).trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

I added the second function since the `result` variable in the first function is always null when clicking anchored links within the same page.

Currently, this works exactly the way I want it to when clicking a footer link on other site pages. However, when I am already on the "services.html" page and click one of the footer links on the same page, it doesn't work the first time I click but instead works the second time the anchored link is clicked.

Desired behavior is of course for it to work the same, regardless of the page on which the footer link is clicked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a sidenote: `$(document).ready(function(){});` alias `$(function(){});` does exactly what you need: It runs the function once the HTML structure has completed loading. No need anymore to put it at the end of the body.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct... however for other reasons, on this site all scripts are loaded at the end of the body, including jQuery, so the above script must be as well.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd assume your administration does not want to create unnecessary JavaScript overheads before the actual website is loaded, which is a reasonable thing to do when working with social networking APIs, for example.

Comment: Well... considering what you say about the code working on other pages... I'm quite sure the problem comes from the fact that you are on the same page. Which would mean that the problem is either in the $document.ready doing something wrong or on the click handler... did you check what exactly is happening when you click the first time ? there is probably a part of the code working... and you could find what the problem is in debug.

Comment: Yes Lyth, precisely. It works fine when arriving from another page, but does not when the target page is the current page. What seems to be happening is that in regards to the second function, the `target` variable is not getting populated on the very first click. On all subsequent clicks, it gets populated. I don't yet understand why this is the case.

Comment: Can you tell me what the url looks like after your first click ?

Comment: Strangely enough, the anchor is indeed appended to the URL on the first click... somehow in a way I still don't understand, window.location.hash did not assign a fragment to `target` on the first click as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it... when you are already on the services.html page, something behaves badly. This could be the href="services.html#sa". Although I don't know what exactly could be wrong, I would recommend retrieving your "#anchor" differently.

Something like

```
$(".exp").click(function(){
  $a = $(this).find("a").first() ;
  href = $a.attr('href') ;
  // parse the href to retrieve #anchor
}) ;
```

This way, you wouldn't depend on window.location... which may behave badly when you are already on services.html.

Comment: Did you read the entire problem? He clearly pointed out that his code is placed at the end of his body tag. Thus there is no problem with binding a click event to non-existing `.ext` class'ed elements. (Edit: Now with your edit, it sounds more reasonable to address that.)

Comment: Seems he "loads" a page. In which case there can be new DOM elements. I'm not sure though to have understood the mechanic, I may have read the code too fast and visualize a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure if he really AJAX-loads it. We'd need feedback from the asker. But since he said it works on second click, I'm in doubt he is performing such a request.

Comment: Yep, I'm not sure either.

Comment: The page is not loaded via AJAX. Essentially, the problem lies in the fact that in the second function, `target` is not assigned a value the very first time one of the anchored footer links is clicked when the user is already on the "services.html" page. On subsequent clicks, it is populated. Very peculiar....

Comment: Ok. Hang on. I may have a solution.

Comment: Lyth, I can't thank you enough after wrestling with this problem for ~2hrs. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Cool :D and strange indeed.